# ffmpeg creating image slideshow in audio concat command

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, command-prompt, slideshow

I have a working ffmpeg which when ran in windows 10 command prompt will combine 3 audio files with 1 image file into a video.
The single image file is used as just a static image for the entire video's duration. (16:50 or 1010 seconds)

```
song1.mp3 00:00:00-00:06:23
song2.mp3 00:06:23-00:12:04
song3.wav 00:12:04-00:16:50
```

I am trying to change this so that instead of a single static image, I have a slideshow of 4 different images play during the duration of the video.
I was thinking of doing this by taking the total length in seconds (1010) divided by 4 would mean 252.5 seconds per image, so a timeline like:

```
img1: 0     - 252.5
img2: 252.5 - 505
img3: 505   - 757.5
img4: 757.5 -  252.5
```

How can I change my command so that the output video is a slideshow of images with the timestamps above?
Here is my working ffmpeg command with explanation from myself which hopefully explains some of it :

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 2 -i "C:\Users\...local_filepath...\ffmpeg-commands\images\img1.png" -i "C:\Users\...local_filepath...\ffmpeg-commands\audio files\song1.mp3" -i "C:\Users\...local_filepath...\ffmpeg-commands\audio files\song2.mp3" -i "C:\Users\...local_filepath...\ffmpeg-commands\audio files\song3.wav" -c:a pcm_s32le -filter_complex concat=n=3:v=0:a=1 -vcodec libx264 -bufsize 3M -filter:v "scale=w=640:h=638,pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2" -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest -tune stillimage -t 1010 "C:\Users\...local_filepath...\ffmpeg-commands\videos\outputvideo.mkv"


ffmpeg

//loop single image 
-loop 1 
//set video framerate
-framerate 2 
//take image and audio files
-i "C:\Users\...local_filepath...\ffmpeg-commands\images\img1.png" 
-i "C:\Users\...local_filepath...\ffmpeg-commands\audio files\song1.mp3" 
-i "C:\Users\...local_filepath...\ffmpeg-commands\audio files\song2.mp3" 
-i "C:\Users\...local_filepath...\ffmpeg-commands\audio files\song3.wav"
//set audio codec
-c:a pcm_s32le 
//organize the audio files (?)
-filter_complex concat=n=3:v=0:a=1 
//set video codec
-vcodec libx264 
//limiting the output bitrate
-bufsize 3M 
//scale single image to 640x638 resolution
-filter:v "scale=w=640:h=638,pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2" 
//range of the CRF scale is 0–51, where 0 is lossless (for 8 bit only, for 10 bit use -qp 0), 23 is the default, and 51 is worst quality
-crf 18 
//set pixel format
-pix_fmt yuv420p 
//try to ensure video is not longer then concatenated audio files
-shortest 
//use still image 
-tune stillimage 
//specify output video time to ensure it is exactly the same length as concattenated audio
-t 1010 
//specify output filepath
"C:\Users\...local_filepath...\ffmpeg-commands\videos\outputvideo.mkv"
```

And here is the command raw how you would run it.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 2 -i "C:\Users\marti\Documents\projects\jan2023-rendertune\ffmpeg-commands\images\img1.png" -i "C:\Users\marti\Documents\projects\jan2023-rendertune\ffmpeg-commands\audio files\song1.mp3" -i "C:\Users\marti\Documents\projects\jan2023-rendertune\ffmpeg-commands\audio files\song2.mp3" -i "C:\Users\marti\Documents\projects\jan2023-rendertune\ffmpeg-commands\audio files\song3.wav" -c:a pcm_s32le -filter_complex concat=n=3:v=0:a=1 -vcodec libx264 -bufsize 3M -filter:v "scale=w=640:h=638,pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2" -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest -tune stillimage -t 1010 "C:\Users\marti\Documents\projects\jan2023-rendertune\ffmpeg-commands\videos\concatVideo-250771.mkv"
```

And here is my ffmpeg version info:

```
ffmpeg version 4.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200621
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libgsm --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
```

Comment: -loop 1 -t 6:23 -i img1.png -loop 1 -t 5:40 -i img2.png -i song1.mp3 ... -filter_complex ...concat...

Answer (score 1):

We may use [loop](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#loop) filer for each frame, and concat the "looped" frames:

`ffmpeg -r 2 -i img1.png -r 2 -i img2.png -r 2 -i img3.png -r 2 -i img4.png -i song1.mp3 -i song2.mp3 -i song3.wav -filter_complex "[4:a][5:a][6:a]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[a];[0:v]scale=w=640:h=638,setsar=1,loop=505:505[v0];[1:v]scale=w=640:h=638,setsar=1,loop=505:505[v1];[2:v]scale=w=640:h=638,setsar=1,loop=505:505[v2];[3:v]scale=w=640:h=638,setsar=1,loop=505:505[v3];[v0][v1][v2][v3]concat=n=4:v=1:a=0,pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2[v]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:a pcm_s32le -c:v libx264 -bufsize 3M -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p  -tune stillimage -t 1010 outputvideo.mkv`

For making the command shorter, assume all the files are in the same folder.

---

- `-r 2` before each input image sets framerate of the input video to 2fps.
- `[4:a][5:a][6:a]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[a]` - concatenate the audio input files as in your question.
- `[0:v]scale=w=640:h=638,setsar=1` and `[1:v]scale=w=640:h=638,setsar=1` ... - scales each one of the images to size 640x638 (assume the input images may have different sizes, we have to scale each image, before concatenating).
  `setsar=1` Makes sure that all the concatenated videos have the same SAR (Storage Aspect Ratio), and usually avoids aspect ratio deformation.
- `loop=505:505` - Uses loop filter for repeating each image 505 times (505 times at 2Hz applies 252.5 seconds).
  The fist `505` is the number of loops, the second `505` is the number of frames in each loop (they should have the same value).
  `[0:v]scale=w=640:h=638,loop=505:505[v0]` - applies scale filter, then loop 505 times, and store the result with temporary name `[v0]`.
- `[v0][v1][v2][v3]concat=n=4:v=1:a=0` - concatenate the 4 videos (after scaling and looping).
- `pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2[v]` applies padding to the concatenated videos.
- `-map "[v]" -map "[a]"` maps the video `[v]` to the output video channel, and the autio `[a]` to the output audio channel.
- Since we have `-t 1010`, we don't need the `-shortest` argument (the output duration is defined to be 1010 seconds).

Comment: Good idea on putting all the files in the same folder just to make things easier. I did that and tried to run this command, but the result gave me some errors: `[Parsed_concat_9 @ 000001fdcbcb5b00] Input link in0:v0 parameters (size 640x638, SAR 48807:64000) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (640x638, SAR 319:320)`

and `[Parsed_concat_9 @ xxx] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_concat_9
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #3:0
Conversion failed!`

Comment: here were the files i used, im thinking the error might be because the resolutions of my image files differ too much? https://www.dropbox.com/s/0oaydmsb1hw1uzo/audio_and_image_files.zip?dl=0

Comment: You are right, I forgot to add `setsar=1`. I updated the answer. Note: I tested my solution with input images that have the same aspect ratio (square images), so my original solution worked without it.

Comment: I have a question about the line `[4:a][5:a][6:a]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[a];`. I understand that `n-3` because there are three audio files to concatenate. but why are the numbers 4, 5, and 6, used for the part `[4:a][5:a][6:a]` ? @Rotem

Comment: The input files are numbered in sequential order starting from zero: `img1.png` number is `[0]`, `img2.png` is `[1]`, ... `song1.mp3` is numbered `[4]`, `song2.mp3` is `[5]` and `song3.wav` is `[6]`. `[4:a]` applies the audio stream of input `[4]`.

Comment: thanks, that makes more sense. im going to try to render another video, similar, but make it so 6 images transition one to the other every 30 seconds. like show img1 from 0-30, img2 from 30-60, img 3from 60-90, etc repeat for the entire video

Comment: i guess what im wondering is, if i want to automate it so it slideshow cycles through 3 different images, showing an image for 30seconds before transitioning to the next, in a loop for the full duration of a video ( like a 2 hour video ) do i need to add a `[2:v]scale=w=640:h=638,setsar=1,loop=505:505[v2];` line for each time an img is on the screen? that seems like it would be an insanely huge complex_filter line, is there any better way to tell ffmpeg to automate this? @rotem

Comment: One option is creating short video files without audio, and using [concat demuxer](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer) (using a text file with a list of files) for concatenating the video files (without re-encoding). Using programming (e.g. Python script) I think there are better options.

Comment: I a new similar question, how to specify padding for particular images to they are not stretched or cropped in the slideshow? such as add black ( or a different color, like neon pink) background padding to the second image in a slideshow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75623256/add-padding-to-ffmpeg-slideshow-images-with-different-dimensions

Comment: facing a new issue, this solution has worked for small amount of files, but I was trying to run the command for 2,000 audio files (yes really) but all the `-i filename` lines make the command so large it is unable to run. i am trying to use a different input method such as a text file, but it is not working with the filter_complex solution you posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75935508/ffmpeg-filter-complex-doesnt-work-with-text-file-input?noredirect=1#comment133935816_75935508 @Rotem

Comment: For 2000  audio files it is recommended to use  concat demuxer (using a text file with a list of files). In case it's not working with `filter_complex`, try using two commands - create MKV with audio only, create MKV with video only, and merge the audio and video into the final MKV file. Use `-c copy` for avoiding re-encoding.