# add padding to ffmpeg slideshow images with different dimensions

Tags: ffmpeg, command-prompt

I have an ffmpeg command which takes 3 audio files and 3 image files, and concats the 3 audio files into a video with length 870.04 seconds, where the images play in a slideshow where each image is shown for 290.015 seconds.

You can copy and paste the command into your web browser search bar to turn it into one line, then run it (filepaths are formatted for win10 command prompt)

```
ffmpeg 
-r 2 -i "E:\myFolder\10. Deejay Punk-Roc - Knock 'em All The Way Out.aiff"
-r 2 -i "E:\myFolder\11. Deejay Punk-Roc - Spring Break.aiff"
-r 2 -i "E:\myFolder\12. Deejay Punk-Roc - Fat Gold Chain.aiff"
-r 2 -i "E:\myFolder\1_front.jpg"
-r 2 -i "E:\myFolder\2_back.jpg"
-r 2 -i "E:\myFolder\3_cd.jpg"

-filter_complex "[0:a][1:a][2:a]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[a];[3:v]scale=w=600:h=593,setsar=1,loop=580.03:580.03[v3];[4:v]scale=w=600:h=593,setsar=1,loop=580.03:580.03[v4];[5:v]scale=w=600:h=593,setsar=1,loop=580.03:580.03[v5];[v3][v4][v5]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0,pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2[v]"

-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:a pcm_s32le -c:v libx264 -bufsize 3M -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p -tune stillimage -t 870.04 

"E:\myFolder\newOutputVid.mkv"
```

The most complex part of this command, which is the logic behind how long to show each image, is the filter_complex argument, which I will try to explain below:

```
-filter_complex "

//concat the three audio files. [0:a] is referring to the 0'th file input which is audio file 'Knock 'em All The Way Out'
[0:a][1:a][2:a]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[a];

//file input 3, is the first image, 
[3:v]scale=w=600:h=593,setsar=1,loop=580.03:580.03[v3];[4:v]scale=w=600:h=593,setsar=1,loop=580.03:580.03[v4];[5:v]scale=w=600:h=593,setsar=1,loop=580.03:580.03[v5];

//concat the three images in order
//set output resolution
[v3][v4][v5]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0,pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2[v]"
```

With the output video that gets rendered, the first image is shown correctly, because the video resolution 600w x 593h is the same as the image itself
[image]

The second image however, was stretched to fit the frame of the video.
[image]

**How can i edit my filter_complex line for the `[4:v]`, the 4th input file which is the second image `2_back.jpg`, so that the image is not stretched? Maybe like add black background padding to keep the image fully visible with the frame and not cropped/stretched**

Download files:
http://www.mediafire.com/folder/e8ja1n8elszk1lu,dxw4vglrz7polyh,ojjx6kcqruksv5r,lah9rano4svj46o,q5jg0083vbj9y1p,d3pt8ydf3ulqm5m/shared

Comment: pad `scale=600:594:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease, pad=600:594:-1:-1, setsar=1`

Comment: I was able to solve it I think, by changing the second img filter_complex part to be `[4:v]pad=600:593:0:63:color=black,setsar=1,loop=580.03:580.03[v4];`

Answer (score 0):

fixed with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -r 2 -i "E:\martinradio\Soulseek Downloads\deejay punk-roc - spoiling it for everyone\10. Deejay Punk-Roc - Knock 'em All The Way Out.aiff" -r 2 -i "E:\martinradio\Soulseek Downloads\deejay punk-roc - spoiling it for everyone\11. Deejay Punk-Roc - Spring Break.aiff" -r 2 -i "E:\martinradio\Soulseek Downloads\deejay punk-roc - spoiling it for everyone\12. Deejay Punk-Roc - Fat Gold Chain.aiff" -r 2 -i "E:\martinradio\Soulseek Downloads\deejay punk-roc - spoiling it for everyone\1_front.jpg" -r 2 -i "E:\martinradio\Soulseek Downloads\deejay punk-roc - spoiling it for everyone\2_back.jpg" -r 2 -i "E:\martinradio\Soulseek Downloads\deejay punk-roc - spoiling it for everyone\3_cd.jpg" 

-filter_complex "
[0:a][1:a][2:a]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[a];

[3:v]scale=w=600:h=593,setsar=1,loop=580.03:580.03[v3];

[4:v]pad=600:593:0:63:color=black,setsar=1,loop=580.03:580.03[v4];

[5:v]scale=w=600:h=593,setsar=1,loop=580.03:580.03[v5];

[v3][v4][v5]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0,pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2[v]"

 -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:a pcm_s32le -c:v libx264 -bufsize 3M -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p -tune stillimage -t 870.04 "E:\martinradio\Soulseek Downloads\deejay punk-roc - spoiling it for everyone\44.mkv"
```

which adds padding for the second img

```
[4:v]pad=600:593:0:63:color=black,setsar=1,loop=580.03:580.03[v4];
```

right here

```
pad=600:593:0:63:color=black
```

I udnerstand 600 and 593 are the resolution, but am not sure what `0:63` is yet