# How to fill small gaps in a contour in opencv

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, opencv

Here is the binary image i am working with:
[image]

I am iterating over a bunch of contours and trying to color them, Here is what i have so far:

```
 input_image = imread(img)
_retval, thresh = cv2.threshold(input_image, 125, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image=thresh, mode=cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
output = np.zeros((input_image.shape[0], input_image.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
for i, contour in enumerate(contours):
   cv2.drawContours(output, contours, i, (255,0,0), thickness=3)
```

the code above works and gives the following output:
[image]

What i want is to have those gaps filled, i can achieve this by changing the thickness to cv2.FILLED, but when i do that i get the following output:

[image]

i just want the lines to be filled up without having the big blobs being filled as well, i want that to remain transparent or without any color, any help would be appreciated, please let me know if i need to clarify anything.

Comment: What does `input_image` look like? It is often easier to fix the first few steps, or do some suitable pre-processing, than trying to fix the broken output afterwards.

Comment: @CrisLuengo the input is a binary image, i attached it above

Comment: ```cv.morphologyEx(img, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)```  help?   find contous + fill contours = original image ?

Comment: @kenash0625 tried it, doesnt give the desired output

Comment: we need to see the source image, not the binarized image.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz unfortunately i dont have the source image, the binarized is all i have

Comment: I can't understand what is the problem. You already have binary mask. So why don't use the mask as is? Assuming that there is a real need to draw the contour... is there any problem to draw both of contour and the original mask?

Answer (score 0):

For colorizing the mask with red color, we don't have to find contours, we may simply set `thresh` as the red color channel of a BGR image (the green and the blue channel are zeros):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

input_image = cv2.imread('input_image.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # Read input image as grayscale.
_retval, thresh = cv2.threshold(input_image, 125, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
output = np.zeros((input_image.shape[0], input_image.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)

output[:, :, 2] = thresh  # Set thresh as the red color channel of the output image (blue and green channels are zeros).

cv2.imwrite('output.png', output)
```

---

Output:
[image]

---

In case the desired output is thicker lines, we may draw the contours over the colored output:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

input_image = cv2.imread('input_image.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # Read input image as grayscale.
_retval, thresh = cv2.threshold(input_image, 125, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
output = np.zeros((input_image.shape[0], input_image.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)

output[:, :, 2] = thresh  # Set thresh as the red color channel of the output image (blue and green channels are zeros).

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image=thresh, mode=cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
#output = np.zeros((input_image.shape[0], input_image.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
for i, contour in enumerate(contours):
    cv2.drawContours(output, contours, i, (0,0,255), thickness=3)

cv2.imwrite('output.png', output)
```

---

Output:
[image]

Comment: i am doing more analysis on the lines so importing them as red is not an option, some of the lines will have other colors as well

Comment: Your input image is black/white image. I can't see any other colors... The gaps are the are just the pixels that are red in the second image and black in your image. What is your actual question?

Comment: @Rotem hey rotem could you look at my most recent comment on the very bottom of this post? Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74967716/ffmpeg-creating-image-slideshow-in-audio-concat-command

Comment: @afkvision I think you may use `cv2.connectedComponents` method instead of `cv2.findContours`, but I can't guess your objectives.