# ffmpeg filter_complex doesn't work with text file input

Tags: bash, audio, ffmpeg, command-prompt

I have a working ffmpeg command that takes 4 input files
https://file.io/DllNlkCqX6J6

(2 audio, 2 images) and then renders a .mkv video, using a filter_complex string which tells ffmpeg to concat the two audio files and make a slideshow for the two images.

The filter_complex string relies on the order of the input files.

For example: `[0:a][1:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[a]` in filter_complex tells ffmpeg to take the index=0 input audio file, and the index=1 input audio file, and concat them.

Then, the the `[2:v]` part tells ffmpeg to take the index=2 image file (we start counting index at zero, so index=2 is really the 3rd file, which is '3.sidea.jpg')

```
ffmpeg 

-r 2 -i "C:\Users\martin\Documents\album\a1 - in the beginning.mp3" 
-r 2 -i "C:\Users\martin\Documents\album\a2 - stratovarious.mp3" 
-r 2 -i "C:\Users\martin\Documents\album\3 sidea.jpg" 
-r 2 -i "C:\Users\martin\Documents\album\4 sideb.jpg" 

-filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[a];[2:v]scale=w=1920:h=1920:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1920:-1:-1:color=white,setsar=1,loop=309.95:309.95[v2];[3:v]scale=w=1920:h=1920:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1920:-1:-1:color=white,setsar=1,loop=309.95:309.95[v3];[v2][v3]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0,pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2[v]" 

-map [v] -map [a] -c:a pcm_s32le -c:v libx264 -bufsize 3M -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p -tune stillimage -t 309.95 
"C:\Users\martin\Documents\album\working.mkv"
```

This command works, but I use the same format for, say, 2k+ audio input files, I reach the terminal command line char limit. So I am trying to move my input files to a text file `input_files.txt`:

```
file 'C:\Users\martin\Documents\album\a1 - in the beginning.mp3'
file 'C:\Users\martin\Documents\album\a2 - stratovarious.mp3'
file 'C:\Users\martin\Documents\album\3 sidea.jpg'
file 'C:\Users\martin\Documents\album\4 sideb.jpg'
```

The same files, in the same order. But running my new command with this input_text.txt file:

```
ffmpeg 

-f concat -safe 0 -i input_files.txt

-filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[a];[2:v]scale=w=1920:h=1920:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1920:-1:-1:color=white,setsar=1,loop=309.95:309.95[v2];[3:v]scale=w=1920:h=1920:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1920:-1:-1:color=white,setsar=1,loop=309.95:309.95[v3];[v2][v3]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0,pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2[v]" 

-map [v] -map [a] -c:a pcm_s32le -c:v libx264 -bufsize 3M -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p -tune stillimage -t 309.95 
"C:\Users\martin\Documents\album\working.mkv"
```

Results in an error about the filter_complex index numbers:

```
[mp3 @ 0000025d87057700] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, concat, from 'input_files.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 320 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s
Invalid file index 1 in filtergraph description [0:a][1:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[a];[2:v]scale=w=1920:h=1920:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1920:-1:-1:color=white,setsar=1,loop=309.95:309.95[v2];[3:v]scale=w=1920:h=1920:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1920:-1:-1:color=white,setsar=1,loop=309.95:309.95[v3];[v2][v3]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0,pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2[v].
```

Almost like it's treating the `-i input_files.txt` as its own index=0 file. I've tried different fixes but no luck.

**How can I use my filter_complex string with a text file as the source of my ffmpeg command file inputs?**

Comment: `-i` inputs can't be entered from a text file. You can use a text file for inputs to the concat demuxer, in which case, you won't need the concat filter.

Comment: how can i enter inputs with a text file because without a text file i hit the command length limit eventually

Comment: ffmpeg can read filters from a file with the -filter_complex_script option, and you can import streams from files using the movie/amovie filters

Comment: so i have to re-write my complex_filter to use a different method such as movie/amovie?